Why does my Pthon code fails to deploy in Google?
I'm trying to deploy a Python code in Google to fetch its results in VBA. The code runs well in PyCharm but returns error 500 from Google
Requirements
    scipy
    flask==2.0.3
    werkzeug==2.0.3
    pandas
    numpy
    statsmodels
    google-cloud-storage

Python
from statsmodels.stats.multicomp import pairwise_tukeyhsd
from google.cloud import storage


def tukey_hsd(request):
    # Initialize the storage client
    storage_client = storage.Client()
    bucket_name = "your-bucket-name"  # Replace with your GCS bucket name
    bucket = storage_client.bucket(bucket_name)
    
    # Load the CSV file into a DataFrame
    # For cloud function testing, you can simulate data instead of loading a CSV file from local disk
    data = pd.DataFrame({
        0: [5, 5.5, 6, 7, np.nan],
        1: [6, 7, 8, np.nan, 9],
        2: [7, 8, 9, 8.5, np.nan]
    })

    # Prepare values and groups arrays
    values = []
    groups = []
    group_names = ['Group1', 'Group2', 'Group3']

    for i, group_name in enumerate(group_names):
        # Convert all values in the column to numeric, setting non-numeric values to NaN
        numeric_col = pd.to_numeric(data[i], errors='coerce')

        # Drop missing (NaN) values
        col_values = numeric_col.dropna().values

        # Add to values list and assign group labels
        values.extend(col_values)
        groups.extend([group_name] * len(col_values))

    # Convert lists to NumPy arrays
    values = np.array(values)
    groups = np.array(groups)

    # Perform Tukey HSD test
    tukey_result = pairwise_tukeyhsd(endog=values, groups=groups, alpha=0.05)

    # Convert results to DataFrame and extract p-adj values
    summary_df = pd.DataFrame(data=tukey_result.summary().data[1:], columns=tukey_result.summary().data[0])
    p_adj_values = summary_df["p-adj"]

    # Save p-adj values as a CSV in-memory file
    csv_data = p_adj_values.to_csv(index=False, header=False)

    # Define the destination blob name and upload the CSV data
    blob = bucket.blob("p_adj_values.csv")
    blob.upload_from_string(csv_data, content_type="text/csv")

    # Return a response indicating the file was saved
    return json.dumps({"message": "p-adj values saved to Google Cloud Storage"}), 200, {"Content-Type": "application/json"}


Check the google error log to see what the actual error is.

Please revise your question to clarify exactly what "trying to deploy" involves (specific commands/services) and what you did to receive a 500 including salient details from the response.

Where are you deploying your code? on which service?

I added some clarification

What Google Cloud products or services are you using to deploy the Python code?

https://console.cloud.google.com/functions

Since you mentioned in the comment section that you are using Cloud Run Functions as the service, I recommend reviewing this documentation, which will guide you on how to deploy a Cloud Run function from source code and help you understand the build process during deployment.
As suggested also by John, you can also view runtime logs for Cloud Run Functions in the Logs Explorer so you could see the actual error. You can also check the Cloud Run Functions troubleshooting errors page which might help you.
I hope this helps.
